# Large screen simulator xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, ios7, xcode5

This is my first question in this community.
I have just updated my xcode to xcode5 and downloaded all the simulators as well.

The problem is when I run and compile the app as iOS 7 iPhone device, it shows me a large screen which is very annoying, the only way to get the small screen is to run the app under iOS 6.

Is there any setting for this issue?
I couldn't a screenshot because I am new here.

I have macbook air 13".
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to scale the iPhone simulator screen:

```
iOS Simulator > Window > Scale menu.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> (50%) to scale to smallest.

And <kbd>1</kbd> is 100, <kbd>2</kbd> is 75%.